# In PyCharm, I have an unresolved reference when calling nose.tools.assert_equals?

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm, nose, nosetests

When I try to use pycharm with nose, I get red underlines with "unresolved reference" when calling assert_raises. I'm using a virtualenv interpreter, but nose is installed and can be run from ipython. Also, running nosetests on actual tests shows no error.

The code I'm running is:

```
from nose.tools import *

def test1():
    assert_equals(1,1)
```

Again, nose runs fine, but the linting mechanism in pycharm thinks this is an error. Any help on configuring pycharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced the problem and [submitted a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7614) to YouTrack, please star/vote the issue to track the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been fixed in PyCharm 3.0